# find-and-replace iteration with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am making a text editor for my website, and I need a find-and-replace function that finds each time the text occurs, highlights it, and, if the user chooses to, replaces it. Then it moves onto the next occurrence, and does the same thing.
I saw this code:

```
var haystackText = "";
function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
     if (haystackText.length == 0) {
          haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
     }
     var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
     var replaced = "";
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
     }
     else {
          var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
     }
     document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

but it only works with a div that has text it, and not a textarea, like I have, and also, it finds and/or replaces all of the occurrences at once, instead of iterating through them one by one.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is working with `<Div>` tag then u should work with div tag . just make that div tag editable .

Try this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is an editable div</div>
```

The contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not.

Comment: I am using a texarea, and I'd like to use the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of it.